# After login i got insecure message in magento checkout page?

Tags: magento-1.9

i Get Waring message in my site  **The information you have entered on this page will be sent over an insecure connection and could be read by a third party**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sign, that your shop isn't SSL/TLS encrypted.

1. Get a certificate and
2. install it on the server
3. Change base url (if you ask me both!) to https://yourdomain.com

Comment: i already configured.

Comment: Then check the source, why the form is still submitted to http://

Comment: yes it's submitted in http:// only

Comment: how i fix that..

Comment: hardcoded action, `<base>` tag, no clue.

Comment: Ok i will check